# How to check which version of a product is available in repositories for different ubuntu versions?

Tags: upgrade, repository, official-repositories, redmine

My scenario is like this :
I have installed redmine on my ubuntu 12.04 server, and i installed it using apt-get install redmine.
So we run the latest stable version 1.3.2 (mysql) , some time after that I found out that there is already 1.4 and even 2.x available to download.

So I wanted to upgrade to 1.4 or any other newer version. But I found out that the newer versions are not available on the official repository.

So from now on I want to check which versions are available in the ubuntu repository . Is there probably even a release schedule?

And I heard that I can download redmine 1.4 from repository if I have ubuntu 13.04 , so I wondered how this works? How to check the repository for any other ubuntu version ?

Many Questions, looking for answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browse to http://packages.ubuntu.com/. There, you can search for any package within any Ubuntu version. That will tell you what version of a specific package is available in what Ubuntu version.

There is no release schedule, as packages are added or updated when ready/necessary.

However, there is a changelog that you can check. For instance, if you go to: [Ubuntu – Details for package redmine in raring](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/redmine), you will find a *Changelog* link at the right under *Ubuntu Resources*.

Within your particular Ubuntu version, you can check which versions of a particular package are available, and which one will be installed, using the command `apt-cache policy`. For instance:

```
$ apt-cache policy redmine
redmine:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.3.1-1
  Version table:
     2.3.1-1 0
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/universe amd64 Packages
```

Comment: thank you for nice info. What version are you running that you can download 2.3.1-1 0 ?  I wonder why I only could download 1.3.2 (stable mysql) using apt-get install redmine

Comment: I am running Ubuntu 13.10 "Saucy Salamander", where Redmine 2.3.1 is available. You are running Ubuntu 12.04 "Precise Pangolin", where the most up-to-date available version of Redmine is 1.3.2.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, install the `rmadison` package, then you can do for instance:

```
$ rmadison redmine
 redmine | 0.9.3-1              | lucid/universe         | source, all
 redmine | 0.9.3-1ubuntu0.1     | lucid-updates/universe | source, all
 redmine | 1.3.2+dfsg1-1ubuntu1 | precise/universe       | source, all
 redmine | 1.4.4+dfsg1-1        | quantal/universe       | source, all
 redmine | 1.4.4+dfsg1-2        | raring/universe        | source, all
 redmine | 2.3.1-1              | saucy/universe         | source, all
 redmine | 2.3.3-3.1            | trusty/universe        | source, all
```